# Lipschitz bump function

Tags: special-functions

Does anyone know of an example of a Lipschitz or Holder continuous bump function on $\mathbb{R}^n$? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Bump functions typically are smooth and have compact support, hence they are Lipschitz.

Comment: I suppose the smoothness and the boundedness of the gradient makes it Lipschitz?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that it is because of the mean value theorem.

Comment: Yes, with the mean value theorem and the fact that the gradient is bounded, we can indeed imply that it is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [usual bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) is $C^\infty$ so has all the properties you want.

Comment: actually, they aren´t analytical functions on $\mathbb{R}$, so caution is required.